# P Element copy to Input value and just one select

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

First name repeats and other names can not be selected, where is the problem?
Also, how do I make the choice just one name?

```js
  

function copyTextValue(bf) {
 if(bf.checked)
 var text1 = document.getElementById("names").innerHTML;
 else
 text1='';
 document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
 document.getElementById("Name3").value=text1; 
 }
```

```html
<b>Names</b><hr/>
 

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this);"/><p id='names'>James</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this);"/><p id='names'>Emre</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this);"/><p id='names'>Kate</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this);"/><p id='names'>Berkay</p>

<hr/><b>Form</b><hr/>
<input id="Name2">
<input id="Name3">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/LL5ukynq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used id attribute with same ids so it will not work. so you need to set id with different value and pass it in function.

```js
function copyTextValue(bf,selector) {
 if(bf.checked)
 var text1 = document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML;
 else
 text1='';
 document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
 document.getElementById("Name3").value=text1; 
 }
```

```html
<b>Names</b><hr/>
 

<input type="radio" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this,'names1');"/><p id='names1'>James</p>
<input type="radio" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this,'names2');"/><p id='names2'>Emre</p>
<input type="radio" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this,'names3');"/><p id='names3'>Kate</p>
<input type="radio" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this,'names4');"/><p id='names4'>Berkay</p>

<hr/><b>Form</b><hr/>
<input id="Name2">
<input id="Name3">
```

Comment: Thats working, also can you prevent multiple checked?

Comment: Why you not use radio input to prevent multiple selection? Here I have changed to radio instead of checkbox.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for your interest.